# Decrypt TLS traffic from mobile application

Tags: encryption, tls1.2, wireshark

Application [IOS](https://itunes.apple.com/ru/app/id1441529510)/[Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.salampay.android) has hidden API, so i want to decrypt his traffic to understand which https requests are sending.

I was trying capture packets from `android emulator` which i connected to `mitmproxy`, but "No connection" in the app. I guess certificates problems. I found `Server Hello TLSv1.2` packet where from [open certificates going](https://certs.godaddy.com/repository), but i'm not sure what i can do with them.

Also i connected my iPhone to vpn and decrypted `ESP` traffic, but application's traffic still encrypted and i didn't see sending needed data from server to my phone...

This TLS connection using: `tls_ecdhe_rsa_with_aes_256_cbc_sha`

[image]

**Question:** Is it even possible to decrypt TLS 1.2 from Android or IOS anyways? Or maybe decrypt only https requests..?

Could provide any extra needed information

Answer (score 1):

Decrypting the payload encrypted with TLS 1.2 is only possible if you get a hold of the private key of that API. Other possible approaches would be using MITM attack with proxies like Charles, the way it works by generating new CA root certificate that you manually install on your devices and then it proxy the connection by providing another certificate to the application pretending to be the API (this certificate is self signed with the CA root certificate you have to install manually)

Please note that the application might be using certificate pinning where the above approach would not work without reverse engineering the application and remove the certificate pinning code.

Comment: I wrote in question that i tried MITM attack using `mitmproxy`, but content in the app stopped downloading. In the non encrypted packets i see where from app getting certificates (link in question). Seems like it's not possible :(